# React (jsx) support in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-2017

Is there any way to get any support for jsx-syntax in visual studio? 
preferably for both .js- and .jsx-files

All I get now is squiggly lines over the shop, so anything better than that would be great

I specifically wrote that I not want another IDE just for my react code. For some reason it disappeared from the final text... Now, as the Title suggests:

Is there any way to get any support for jsx-syntax in visual studio 2017?

Comment: You should use Visual Studio Code for it , it;s nice and full of extension and intelligent.